# Master-Detail application in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, master-detail

[image]

Above is my current project structure. Black area is static for every screen, and the white area will be dynamic. I am new in Master-Detail based application. From every tutorial I have read I found that I can't implement the above structure. I just wanted to know is it possible to do that kind of application using Master-Detail technique. If yes then can you please provide me some tutorial or any demo project.

Comment: You'll need to impletement your current structure as yourself. You can use this but not based on the Master-Detail template.

Comment: @DavidAnsermot, so iOS Master-Detail is will not allow to implement this kind of structure. :(

Comment: Exactly what I said.

Comment: Can give some idea to implement this in a best way..

Comment: Make a base view controller with this structure in insert other dedicated (menu, details, etc.) controllers's views inside the areas you created in the base view controller.

Comment: That's mean in my whole application there will be only one view controller and other will be views...

Comment: No, you'll have UIViewController, like for the menu, but you "addsubview:MenuController.view" on your base controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68661/discussion-between-tapas-pal-and-david-ansermot).

Comment: What is the purpose of the tab area? The master view will update the detail view- does the tab view change the options in the master or something? Does it load a completely different controller other than the master/detail?

Comment: @Stonz2 master area is static through out the application... Tab area means there will be list of buttons (not like UITabBar) respecting this tab and tableview will be refreshed and from tableview detail view will refresh.